# Можно ли с помощью XQuery вывести данные в файл или html страницу?

Tags: java, html, xml, xquery

Изучаю XQuery, возникла необходимость вывести данные из XML файла 1)в текстовый файл и 2)на html страницу, причем сделать это средствами XQuery. Можно ли это как-нибудь осуществить? Если есть возможность, то скиньте ссылку что почитать по этому вопросу.
UPD. processor Saxon-HE

Comment: Какой у вас процессор XQuery? Какой API вы используете?

Comment: использую Saxon-HE